Contract creation confusion -- Unsure when my contract was deployed
I deployed a contract on Fuji Testnet around 3 hours ago, the address is as follows: 0xDb3F493F9D4CdaaDA08E30957c59a0e01CfB2af0
I went to Snowtrace to check it out and received an expected record of the contract creation.

The weird part was when I entered the exact contract address on Sepolia Testnet and saw that this contract which I created on Fuji hours ago was created on Sepolia 5 days ago although I have no recollection doing so. (I only wrote the code for this contract today.) What did I mess up? Thank you.


The contract address depends only on your address and the nonce, the code itself doesn't matter. Since they both share the same nonce (= 0) you deployed them at the same address.

Thank you for the response! Does this mean I could get further clashes in contract address in future if nonce=0? How do I prevent it from happening if I would like to stick to my current address to deploy contracts?

It's not a problem if you get the same address on different blockchains. There's no easy solution anyway.

okay, thanks. what's the likelihood it happens on the same blockchain then?

Never on the same blockchain, because the nonce always increases.
